# javascript to have a twitter home page like tweet feed push and wait for new content

Tags: javascript, jquery

Take a look at twitters home page. I want to copy the effect they have were a tweet is pushed down, and then it waits for like 3 seconds, and then a new tweet is pushed down etc.

Anyone know of any tutorials on how to accomplish this.

The answer to this question got me to this solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var events = $('.event')
    setInterval('addEvent()',3000);
    $.each (events, function(i) {
        if (i > 2) {
            $("#" + this.id).addClass('hidden_event');
        }
    }) 
});

function addEvent() {
    var events = $('.event');
    var event_to_append = events[events.length - 1];
    var event_to_remove = events[events.length - 2];
    $('#events').prepend(event_to_append);
    $("#" + event_to_append.id).slideToggle('slow');
    $("#" + event_to_remove.id).fadeOut('fast');
}
```

The `events` variable is a `ul` of `li`'s where the `class="event"` is present on every `li`. The `$.each` loop just hides events by adding a class with `display:none` and hides events beyond the third index. If is not enabled all the events will be present.

The `addEvent()` function gets the events, first the first event to append and the last event to hide and fades then in and out. `slideToggle()` is used to slide the dive down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know any tutorials, but i can tell you generally how they are doing it.
Assuming that you know how to use a setInterval().
if goes like this
Grab new tweet, append() it after a empty reference div, slideToogle() the text and fade it in.

```
$.post("/API/locationForNextTweet", null ,function(data){
      var tweetid = "tweet-id-" + data.TweetID;
      var tweet = "<div id='" + tweetid + "' class='twtr-tweet'><div class='innertweet'>" + data.Tweet + "</div></div>";
     $(".twtr-tweet").append(tweet);
     $("#" + tweetid).slideToggle(function(){
           $("#" + tweetid).fadeIn();
      });
});
```

This is all pretty sloppy code and there is a lot more going on than what i posted so this should give you a head start.  You'll need to use the callback function on the slideToggle() to time the fadeIn() correctly.  and they are probably using a .png at the bottom of the box to make it look like the tweets are fading out but are really just being hidden.

if you have your tweets or whatever object in an array, you would want to use the .each() function

```
var tweets = [<%your data source array here%>]
$.each(tweets, function(){
   var tweetid = "tweet-id" + this['TweetID'];
   var tweet = "<div id='" + tweetid + "' class='twtr-tweet'><div class='innertweet'>" + this['Tweet'] + "</div></div>";
     $(".twtr-tweet").append(tweet);
     $("#" + tweetid).slideToggle(function(){
           $("#" + tweetid).fadeIn();
      });
});
```

Comment: If you want to make it simpler you can forget tweets and calling an api already having an array with items.